# How do you properly test the view in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've seen a few articles on unit testing view models in MVVM and how the tests themselves are consumers of the view models, testing the functionality of the viewModel and model.  However, I'm left wondering how I go about testing the views (UI) to ensure they are wired up to my view models properly.  I don't want to write a test that, for instance, presses a button to make sure something is written to the db as this is effectively testing my VM, which i've already done.

For instance, I'd like to be able to write a test to make sure that a button is wired up to a specific command.  Therefore preventing anyone from coming along and removing the button's command, making it no longer functional.

Is this possible?  thanks.

Comment: IMO if you have your UI logic separated correctly from the rest of your application by following the MVVM, MVP, MVC or similar pattern I've always felt it's not important to test the UI other than with some general acceptance testing.

Comment: Chris, without a UI test how can you be sure that any changes you make don't screw up any existing functionality.  i.e. removing the command on a button causing it to no longer save.

Comment: You were going to test the UI anyway, right? For visual and aesthetic glitches? In doing that you presumably will spot miswirings and incorrect answers. My argument is that UIs tend to be volatile, fields are moved and added, presentation formats are changed. Automating that testing is really tough, maintaining those tests is even tougher. Sometimes we just need to bite the bullet and manually regression test.

Comment: There's always lots of testing of the UI just with the design of it, especially with html/css if you check multiple browsers that adds multiple checks to it. The only time I've ever written code to test UI was using AutoIt scripts with a legacy web app that was horribly designed with super high coupling that unit testing was impossible without breaking the app so I had autoit mash data into forms for me instead of typing myself. I used to laugh at the other developers that would rather spend 6 minutes at a time typing in a loan application while it took me 2 minutes where I could walk off.

Answer (score 4):

But what if someone (hopefully a designer) wants to change the `Button` to a `MenuItem`? Your test will break and you'll have to fix it. One of the major boons of MVVM is that designers can really be free to arrange and rearrange the interface however they like without requiring too much back-and-forth with the developers. Writing unit tests against the UI annuls that boon.

I'm kind of playing Devil's advocate here. I'm not saying testing the UI is completely useless and never has a place in anyone's code base. What I'm saying is that the returns are diminishing, and that you may be trading one problem for another.

As for how you actually test a view in "isolation" . . . the easiest way I think would be to use view models with injected mock services. Your view models can use a service locator to grab dependent services, so your unit tests can inject dummy services. You could then use a combination of named-element references, visual tree crawling, and the WPF UI automation APIs to assert that different visual elements have properties set as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something from Telerik (Art of test) which can help automate the raw UI.
http://www.artoftest.com/products/webaii.aspx
Though now I have looked it up that is Silverlight rather than WPF. Hopefully its a good starting point at least.

Comment: That looks good, but it doesn't answer my question.  I'm specifically after a way of testing things like bindings, commands etc.  Just simply running the UI and checking the end results is not good enough as I'm not interested in testing the VM or the Model, just the views themselves.  The VM or Model could change in future, but I shouldn't have to to also change my view tests.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, its a good question, I had sort of been conveniently ignoring that bit to date.
ASIDE: Depending on the amount of work you want to do you could write a parser / validator to ensure that everything in the model is represetned in the view. Not quite what your looking for maybe but would be a good validation check.